# Sacar valores nulos de dos tablas en concreto con inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando sacar valores null de varias tablas pero con inner join no funciona y he probado ya hasta con is null, dejo aquí varias capturas y la sentencia con la que estoy tratando de sacar.
La cosa está en que cuando inserto un contacto que tiene valores null y no estan en los campos salgan en la consulta.
Gracias de antemano !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT contactos.id_contactos 
    AS id_contactos, 
    contactos.id_paises AS id_paises, 
    contactos.id_etiquetas AS id_etiquetas, 
    contactos.nombre AS nombre, 
    contactos.apellidos AS apellidos, 
    contactos.cumple AS cumple,
    etiquetas.id_etiquetas AS id_etiquetas,
    etiquetas.nombre AS etiqueta, 
    contactos.ciudad AS ciudad,
    paises.nombre_paises AS paises, 
    contactos.telefono AS telefono, 
    contactos.email AS email, 
    contactos.idioma AS idioma, 
    contactos.foto AS foto 
    FROM t_contactos AS contactos 
    INNER JOIN t_etiquetas AS etiquetas ON contactos.id_etiquetas IS NULL = etiquetas.id_etiquetas  
    IS NULL
    INNER JOIN t_paises AS paises ON contactos.id_paises = paises.id_paises ORDER BY id_contactos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que buscas?, que aparezcan todos los contactos independientemente si tienen o no id_etiquetas y id_paises?

```
 SELECT contactos.id_contactos 
        AS id_contactos, 
        contactos.id_paises AS id_paises, 
        contactos.id_etiquetas AS id_etiquetas, 
        contactos.nombre AS nombre, 
        contactos.apellidos AS apellidos, 
        contactos.cumple AS cumple,
        etiquetas.id_etiquetas AS id_etiquetas,
        etiquetas.nombre AS etiqueta, 
        contactos.ciudad AS ciudad,
        paises.nombre_paises AS paises, 
        contactos.telefono AS telefono, 
        contactos.email AS email, 
        contactos.idioma AS idioma, 
        contactos.foto AS foto 
        FROM t_contactos AS contactos 
        LEFT JOIN t_etiquetas AS etiquetas ON contactos.id_etiquetas = etiquetas.id_etiquetas 
        LEFT JOIN t_paises AS paises ON contactos.id_paises = paises.id_paises 
        ORDER BY id_contactos
```